# how to pass uint8_t * to a function as a buffer

Tags: c

I am a C beginner. I am implementing some code in C which will call an interface function with parameters `uint8_t *value` **pass as buffer** and `int32_t *length` **pass as length of buffer**.

```
/*interface function declaration in header file
 * this interface implementation is not under my
 * control. I just call the following function.
 * The return value is 0(successful) or 1(fail)
 */
int get_parameter(uint8_t *value, uint32_t *length);

/*My .c File */
/*can it be passed as buffer? because the function will
 *assign some memory located value to this parameter.
 *uint8_t cant have value greater than 255 but in my
 *case the memory located value can be larger than 255
 */
uint8_t value; 

/*Is it correct ? 
 *This should be the length of the buffer declared above*/
uint32_t length = sizeof(value);

/* interface function call in my code */
int result = get_parameter(&value, &length);

if(result == 0)
{
   char *data;
   int32_t *myValue; /*want to assign what value parameter pointing to*/
   memcpy(data + sizeof(int32_t), &value, length); /*perhaps something like this ?*/

}
```

Value and length are in/out parameters. This interface function will assign value, can be **<** or **>** 255, to value parameter and assign the length of that value **in bytes** to length parameter.

My question is that, how to call interface function `int get_parameter(uint8_t *value, uint32_t *length)` so that it may assign some value to value parameter regardless of size. I am bit confused about value parameter because uint8_t can only have maximum value 255 but in my case it can be greater than 255. I am expecting the solution something like this.

```
char *value; 
uint32_t length = sizeof(value);

/* interface function call in my code */
int result = get_parameter(value, &length);

if(result == 0)
{
   uint32_t *myValue;
   *myValue = atoi(value);
   printf("%d", *myValue); /*it should print whatever the value assigned by the get_parameter function*/
}
```

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry i dont have any example. I have to implement it. If I have an example I dont need to ask the question. I may simply follow the example code.

Comment: What does "that value" refer to?

Comment: @shan I did not ask for example code, example input/output of the function is all I asked for. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once agin to learn what we expect from questions. :)

Comment: @AlanAu value parameter is a buffer. I dont know if I have to define it as char *buffer or how to define it. Thats what i am trying to understand.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have already mentioned the input/output of the function. What else you are expecting ?

Comment: The function accepts two pointers, but based on the information provided it is impossible to tell if these pointers are used to point to input parameters, output parameters, or both. In other words, what does get_parameter do with the pointers? Does it expect the pointers to point to variables already initialised with meaningful values? Or will it return information in the memory pointed to? A common idiom is to have `value` point to a fixed-length buffer, and `length` point to the length of the buffer. On returning, `length` would then be updated with the number of bytes written to `value`.

Comment: @CarstenHansen correct, the function will assign pointers with some information in the memory pointed to.

Comment: In that case, after `get_parameter` returns `length` will contain the value set in `get_parameter`. There is no need to copy or convert it; you can use `length` directly.

Comment: there are alot of negative reviews. Is it possible to remove it and ask again ? I will write in detail

Comment: "This interface function will assign some value, can be < or > 255, to value parameter and assign the length of that value in bytes to length parameter." This is not nearly enough. You need to know what the parameter you are trying to obtain *means*. You need to know how to interpret it. Knowing that its length is 147 bytes is useless if you don't know what *is* in these bytes.

Comment: i hope the question is clear now or do i need to explain it more ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `get_parameter` returns an `int32_t` in the memory pointed to by `value`, here's one way to go about it:

```
int32_t value;
uint32_t length = sizeof(value);

if(get_parameter((uint8_t *)&value, &length) == 0)
{
    // value is an int32_t containing data set by get_parameter()
}
```

Three comments:

1. Prepending the parameters with the `&` (ampersand) character means to take the address of the parameter, which is just another way of saying "pointer to" the parameter.
2. The `(uint8_t *)` casts the type of `&value` to `uint8_t *`, as required by `get_parameter`. Typecasts are sometimes frowned upon but can be difficult to avoid; an alternative solution could be based on passing a `uint8_t` array to `get_parameter` and then using `memcpy` to copy the value back into an `int32_t`, but even then you'd need a couple of (implicit) casts in the `memcpy` call. Also be aware that while casting from `int32_t *` to `uint_8 *` generally works, casting from `uint8_t *` to `int32_t *` (or from any smaller to larger type) can cause alignment issues on some architectures.
3. Finally, the fact that `length` is a pointer implies that `get_parameter` might return the number of bytes actually written to `*value`. If this is the case then, in the interest of correctness, you should check that `length` has the expected contents after the call to `get_parameter`, i.e. check that `length == sizeof(value)`.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. You are passing a buffer of length one, to a function, and expect it to return some length. What kind of length? If this is the length of the result, where the result should fit?

Comment: Based on the question (which has been edited a number of times) I'm finding it hard to come up with a better answer. I had initially assumed it was a question of syntax, i.e. how to pass pointers to `value` and `length`. Without knowing the semantics of `get_parameter` all we can do is guess and/or ask for more information

Comment: The code fails to make sense on its own, regardless of what the poorly worded question currently says.

Comment: Whether it makes sense depends entirely on what one expects get_parameter to do. The original question was: "how can I extract (length) in my calling function". In that context it seemed reasonable to me to demonstrate the use of the `&` character, and explain that `length` is already available without "extracting" or casting anything

Comment: In short you are saying, in effect, "I have no idea what the function does, here's a call that follows the static language rules and will not make the compiler scream, if it crashes and burns at run time that's your problem". Except you are not saying that explicitly. You should.